# PostgreSQL: deduplicate inserts, but preserve uniqueness for a column subset

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-triggers

I would like to keep a table of distinct places, with a restrictive UNIQUE (name, address) constraint.

When importing a new place, if it has a new (name, address) tuple I can insert it directly and get back the new id, if it fully matches an existing row (modulo administrative columns like created_at), I want to get back the existing id, but if it matches an existing (name, address) and other columns have a discrepancy, I want Postgres to complain about breaking the (name, address) uniqueness constraint.

Something like `ON CONFLICT (name, address) REQUIRE (EXCLUDED.x, EXCLUDED.y) = (x, y) AND DO NOTHING`.

It feels like it might be possible to contort a `DO UPDATE SET` clause that will either update zero columns or `RAISE`, but I haven't managed it; or if this is outside what `ON CONFLICT` can do, maybe triggers would be flexible enough.

Conceptually I just want a table that deduplicates inserts.

```
CREATE TABLE places (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    x FLOAT NOT NULL,
    y FLOAT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    UNIQUE(name, address)
);
```

Comment: I'd write a plpgsql function like `new_place(name, address, x, y)` returning id for that task.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing a BEFORE INSERT trigger, but short circuiting the insert does break INSERT … RETURNING. So maybe a function will be best.